# cordova でデバッグした時にTTSというプラグイン が非推奨API使っているとエラー

Tags: android, cordova

今ちゃんと動いているアプリをcordovaで、直接buildする環境で作り直しています。
理由は、使いたい広告プラグインを使えるようにしたかったからです。

でも、今回buildしたら、音声合成のTTSの方が非推奨APIを使っているとエラーになりました。

> :compileDebugJavaWithJavac注意:/Users/xxx/zzz/platforms/android/src/com/wordsbaking/cordova/tts/TTS.javaは非推奨のAPIを使用またはオーバーライドしています。
>   注意:詳細は、-Xlint:deprecationオプションを指定して再コンパイルしてください。

buildする時に、-Xlint:deprecationを付けたら、無事に buildできます。
でも、TTSのプラグインは、キモなので使いたいです。
今回のオプションの意味を調べようと検索しましたが、見つかりません。
今回エラーで出てきたオプションの意味を教えて頂けましたら、幸いです。

また、回避策も知りたいです。
教えて頂けましたら、幸いです。

ネット検索して、下記の記事を見つけました。
プラグインの順番を変えても、ダメでした。
http://www.kumakake.com/%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2/3892

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/123200

Answer (score 0):

他の質疑応答のサイトで、-Xlint:unchecked　を教えて頂けました。
これを試したら、ビルドの時に、警告が出なくなりました。